# Fill columns of a table with data from a multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

I'm trying to fill a table with moment.js objects with each date's values on each column. The array I'm trying to fill the table with looks like this:

```
[['8th Jan 11AM', '8th Jan 12AM'],['9th Jan 11AM', '9th Jan 12AM'],['10th Jan 11AM', '10th Jan 12AM']]
```

I'm creating that array as so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    thisMoment = moment().day(i);

    var dayDateStamps = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        dayDateStamps.push(thisMoment.startOf('day').add(j + 6, 'hours').format('lll'));
    }
    dateStamps.push(dayDateStamps);

}
```

To generate the table I'm doing this:

```
function bodyFromDateStamps(dateStamps) {
    var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < countMultiArray(dateStamps); i++) {
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            row = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
        }
        row.insertCell(i % 7).innerHTML = dateStamps[i % 7][i];
    }
}

function countMultiArray(array) {
    var iter = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            iter += 1
        }
    }
    return iter;
}
```

However, currently I'm getting this:
[image: Table Cells Undefined]

I get the right amount of cells (84) however the content is stopping after 1 iteration of an 'hour' loop. I can't work out where I've gone wrong here.

How can I fix this issue and is there a better way to solve this problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is generating the table.

You are iterating from 0 to 83, and trying to access an inner array by that `i`. You are accessing the first array correctly using modulus, but the 2nd array index should also be bound to a 0-6 value index, so do this:

```
row.insertCell(i % 7).innerHTML = dateStamps[i % 7][Math.floor(i/12)];
```

`Math.floor(i/12)` will correctly find the 2nd index in a 0 - 83 iteration.

BTW: `countMultiArray` can be replaced with `7 * 12`, no need for that function because you already know the values.